# different models on one attribute in sailsjs

Tags: model, sails.js

I'm currently setting up my models in a  Sails.js application and was wondering if there was a possibility to solve my little problem nicely:

So I want to express the following relation:
A document has content, which is either of (model) type A or type B. 
Is there a way to express this without merging type A and B into one big model or adding one attribute for each type on the document model? 
Maybe something like `enums` for models and not for strings (if that's possible).

Or do I have to do the lookup via a unique ID like:

```js
// model Document
module.exports = {

    contentType: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        enum: ['typeA', 'typeB'],
    },
    contentID: {
       type: 'integer',
       required: true
    },
}

// model typeA
module.exports = {

    id: {
        type: 'integer',
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    heading: {
       type: 'string',
       required: true
    },
    body: {
       type: 'string',
       required: true
    },
}
```

Ideally I just want to write:

```js
// model Document
module.exports = {

    contentType: {
        model: ['typeA', 'typeB'],
    },
}
```

or something like that (if that's possible).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it can't be done without any application logic. Because SQL (also Sails/ Waterline relation) model is use `table-to-table` relation. Your relation, which is `record-to-record` are available in NoSQL `graph db` something like Neo4j, TitanDB, etc. and of course Waterline (currently) still not capable to integrate it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing that as of now, and the approach you're currently using is what I finally settled on after discarding the multiple-attribute approach(which works, but is very irritating to manage).

However, if your models (typeA and typeB) are light and you want to store them under the same attribute anyway, you could declare a [custom  validation](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/concepts/ORM/Validations.md#custom-validation-rules) as follows:

```
//model Document
function isTypeA(content) {
    //check if content is a valid typeA object
}
function isTypeB(content) {
    //check if content is a valid typeB object
}
module.exports = {
    types: {
        typeAOrTypeB: function(content){
            return isTypeA(content) || isTypeB(content);
        }
    },
    attributes: {
        contentType: {
            type: 'string',
            enum: ['typeA', 'typeB']
        },
        content: {
            type: 'json',
            typeAOrTypeB: true
        }
    }
}
```

(I would still prefer the multiple-model approach if `content` were even moderately detailed.)